# Correct format or order json array

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having a problem. From a WebService I receive the following array:

```
"Value": [{
    "celda_id": 1,
    "indicador_id" : 5,
    "valores_celdas": [{
        "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
        "celda_key_valor": "CHECK1"
    }, {
        "celda_key_codigo": "IMAGEN",
        "celda_key_valor": "L76nD.jpg"
    }, {
        "celda_key_codigo": "SUBTEXTO",
        "celda_key_valor": "prueba subtexto 1"
    }, {
        "celda_key_codigo": "TEXTO",
        "celda_key_valor": "Prueba dominio 1"
    }]
}, {
    "celda_id": 7,
    "indicador_id" : 5,
    "valores_celdas": [{
        "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
        "celda_key_valor": "24567"
    }, {
        "celda_key_codigo": "IMAGEN",
        "celda_key_valor": "estrenimiento-gato-bebe2-xl-668x400x80xX.jpg"
    }, {
        "celda_key_codigo": "SUBTEXTO",
        "celda_key_valor": "sd"
    }, {
        "celda_key_codigo": "TEXTO",
        "celda_key_valor": "sdfsdfdsf"
    }]
}]
```

Controller :

```
$scope.getCheckList = function() {
    $scope.show();
    var parametros = { "gsalid": $scope.gsalId, "codcategoria": $scope.categoria_codigo };
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: UrlGetCheckList.url,
        data: JSON.stringify(parametros),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    }).then(function success(response) {
        $scope.hide();
        $scope.groups = response.data.GetCheckListResult.indicadores;
        angular.forEach($scope.groups, function(group, index){
            angular.forEach(group.Value, function(value, index){

            });
        });
    }, function error(response) {
        /* Error llamada */
        $scope.groups = sessionService.get('checklist');
        $scope.hide();

    });
}
```

The issue is that as you can see both arrangements have in common the field "indicator_id". Each of these "cells" is one item, ie:

```
<ion-item>
   IMAGEN : celda_key_valor //celda_key_condigo = IMAGEN
   TEXTO : celda_key_valor //celda_key_codigo = TEXTO
   SUBTEXTO : celda_key_valor //celda_key_codigo = SUBTEXTO
   CODIGO : celda_key_valor //celda_key_codigo = CODIGO
</ion-item>
```

What I have tried to do is:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Value track by item.celda_id" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
    <!-- Indicador tipo 1 -->
    <div ng-show="item.indicador_id == '5'">
        <div ng-repeat="celda in item.valores_celdas track by $index">
            {{celda}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where "celda" is equal to:

```
{
    "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
    "celda_key_valor": "CHECK1"
}, {
    "celda_key_codigo": "IMAGEN",
    "celda_key_valor": "L76nD.jpg"
}, {
    "celda_key_codigo": "SUBTEXTO",
    "celda_key_valor": "prueba subtexto 1"
}, {
    "celda_key_codigo": "TEXTO",
    "celda_key_valor": "Prueba dominio 1"
},
{
    "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
    "celda_key_valor": "24567"
}, {
    "celda_key_codigo": "IMAGEN",
    "celda_key_valor": "estrenimiento-gato-bebe2-xl-668x400x80xX.jpg"
}, {
    "celda_key_codigo": "SUBTEXTO",
    "celda_key_valor": "sd"
}, {
    "celda_key_codigo": "TEXTO",
    "celda_key_valor": "sdfsdfdsf"
}
```

This is not what I expect, since I can not separate them by types. Generate 1 item for each value cell you find and it is not what I need. I know that the problem is the format of the JSON, unfortunately I can not edit the WebService as I receive the data and I need to edit them from the view to be able to display them correctly.

```
<ion-item> celda_id == 1
   IMAGEN : celda_key_valor //celda_key_condigo = IMAGEN
   TEXTO : celda_key_valor //celda_key_codigo = TEXTO
   SUBTEXTO : celda_key_valor //celda_key_codigo = SUBTEXTO
   CODIGO : celda_key_valor //celda_key_codigo = CODIGO
</ion-item>
<ion-item> celda_id == 7
   IMAGEN : celda_key_valor //celda_key_condigo = IMAGEN
   TEXTO : celda_key_valor //celda_key_codigo = TEXTO
   SUBTEXTO : celda_key_valor //celda_key_codigo = SUBTEXTO
   CODIGO : celda_key_valor //celda_key_codigo = CODIGO
</ion-item>
....
```

So it should be for this example or if they came more, ONE ITEM for each `valores_celda`

Comment: Why can't you alter the JSON ? Can you not edit the Javascript code that fetches `Value`?

Comment: Yes, that I can edit, but the WebService is the one that I can not edit. I will update my question and make that clear. @bhantol

Comment: In your controller you can do this `$scope.Value = myValueTransformer(originalValueFromWebService);` and implement `myValueTransformer`

Comment: This is what I am trying to do but without success, so leave this post :/

Comment: You can create a plnkr with Value.json and pointing the plnkr to that file to reproduce the problem. Then I can help in a better way.

Comment: Can you post your controller code ?

Comment: Yes, give me a few minutes and update!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129939/discussion-between-sioesi-and-bhantol).